# C#: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'char'

Tags: c#

I am a new learner and trying to solve a problem on the Leetcode, but there was a compile error.

```
public class Solution 
{
public bool IsValid(string s) 
{
    if(s.Length%2==1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(s.Length==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    Stack st=new Stack();
    for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
            case '(':
            st.Push(s[i]);
            break;
            case'[':
            st.Push(s[i]);
            break;
            case'{':
            st.Push(s[i]);
            break;
            case ')':
            if(st.Count==0||st.Peek()!='(')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                st.Pop();
            }
            break;
            case']':
            if(st.Count==0||st.Peek()!='[')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                st.Pop();
            }
            break;
            case'}':
            if(st.Count==0||st.Peek()!='}')
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                st.Pop();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return st.Count==0;
}
}
```

I get an error.

> Line 28: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'char'

Might be this one

```
if(st.Count==0||st.Peek()!='(')
```

I know this is about datatype, but I don't know how to solve it.

I am not an English speaker so some of my English grammar might be crazy. Sorry about that, and thank you if you can help me.

Comment: if(st.Count==0||st.Peek().ToString() !="(")

Comment: You have to cast the object. Something like: ((char) st.Peek())!='('

Comment: both answers are correct, the problem is that the compiler doesn't know implicitly if the object is a char, so you have to cast it to char o make the stack a stack fo chars

Comment: both 2 answers are correct. but sadly I cannot accept all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are using a Stack without generics.  Your stack is a stack of type `Object`.

You would need to cast the data you pop or peek from your stack to `char`.

example:

```
if(st.Count==0|| (char) st.Peek()!='(')
```

Answer (score 12):

`Stack` stores objects, but you want to store `char` specifically.
Use [Stack<char>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
  Stack<char> st = new Stack<char>();
```

Comment: i vote for this answer because defining the type of the stack will make things easier for any other char related operation